# MySQL : Can't update table 'gradepoint' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I created MySQL syntax with triggers. When entering totalpoint data, the indexpoint column is automatically filled in based on the gradestandardpoint column in the gradestandard table, but I found some problems as follows :

*Can't update table 'gradepoint' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger*

From Code

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_indexpoint_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON gradepoint
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE gradepoint
  SET indexpoint = (SELECT gradestandardpoint FROM gradestandard WHERE lowlimit <= NEW.totalpoint AND uplimit >= NEW.totalpoint)
  WHERE studentid = NEW.studentid AND courseid = NEW.courseid;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

I have created a temporary table to insert data but still can't

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_indexpoint_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON gradepoint
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_gradepoint (
    studentid INT,
    courseid INT,
    indexpoint CHAR(1)
  );

  INSERT INTO temp_gradepoint (studentid, courseid, indexpoint)
  SELECT studentid, courseid, (SELECT gradestandardpoint FROM gradestandard WHERE lowlimit <= NEW.totalpoint AND uplimit >= NEW.totalpoint)
  FROM gradepoint
  WHERE studentid = NEW.studentid AND courseid = NEW.courseid;

  UPDATE gradepoint
  SET indexpoint = (SELECT indexpoint FROM temp_gradepoint WHERE studentid = NEW.studentid AND courseid = NEW.courseid)
  WHERE studentid = NEW.studentid AND courseid = NEW.courseid;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_gradepoint;
END;
```

Table Gradepoint [Table Gradepoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AQCh.png)

Table gradestandard
[Table gradestandard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX2O3.png)

Comment: There is no way round this and it's hard to tell what you are trying to achi1ve solely on the basis of non working code.

Comment: You can adjust NEW. values in a before trigger I suggest you try that route. Need more help? add table definitions,sample data and expected outcome as text,,